# (How) Does Unity3D perform sand-boxing and security?

Tags: security, sandbox, unity-game-engine

Unity3D lets you write scripts in C# which are (IIRC) run through the mono framework on PCs with the Unity player installed.
How does Unity3D sand-box this - I assume they must do - to prevent a malicious site trying to delete your files or report data back to a server about you and your PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unity Player runs it's own version of the Mono runtime that doesn't include file system access.

There's a massive (10MB) list of what Mono/.Net classes are available for each supported platform.

http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/MonoCompatibility.html